# XMLHttprequest not working on local host while running chrome without security

Tags: javascript

My javascript code is working fine on server. It is more convenient to edit it locally. So I disable Chrome security with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security  --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

and CORS error is not showing anymore, but also console is not returning any data.

Here is the code:

```
var asia = "asia.txt";
function loadXMLDoc(loadas) {
var test = loadas;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    obj1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);    
   console.log('My object: ', obj1);
       }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/C:/Users/tom/Desktop/javascript/"+test, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
var manomygas = document.getElementById("mygas");
manomygas.addEventListener("click", ()=>{loadXMLDoc(asia)});
```

In my .txt which I am reading an object:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "Country name": "China",
      "Flag": "CN",
      "Population": 1395380000
    },
    {
      "Country name": "India",
      "Flag": "IN",
      "Population": 1338677000
    },
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: There are numerous ways to quickly set up a localhost server on your machine. That would be a better way to do this. You are missing `file://` protocol in url. Also learn how to use browser dev tools network to inspect the actual requests to see status, url used , response etc. F12 to open dev tools then network tab

Comment: There are numerous web server plugins for IDEs. You can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuichinukiyama.vscode-preview-server for VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and the code is working fine.

Maybe you can't see the data due to a parsing error.

The only thing I changed is adding the closing square brackets in the JSON file and removing the last comma.

JSON code below:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "Country name": "China",
      "Flag": "CN",
      "Population": 1395380000
    },
    {
      "Country name": "India",
      "Flag": "IN",
      "Population": 1338677000
    }
  ]
}
```

I suggest not to use Chrome with flag disable-web-security enabled; instead (on VSCode) install the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension -> open the HTML file and launch the test server.

Simple as it should be without problematic errors:)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not share the whole json. It is actually closed. I will trive live server and get back with the result!

Comment: I could not solve the initial problem. But while using live server it works great! So no need to disable chrome security.